# How to fix correctly use a custom lower_bound

Tags: c++, lower-bound

I'm new to C++. I was trying a leetcode question (436. Find Right Interval). Thought of complicating it by writing my own lower_bound just for my knowledge. But the below code is showing me `runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'value_type' (stl_vector.h)`. I'm unable to understand what's the issue, would someone please clarify what I'm doing wrong.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> findRightInterval(vector<Interval>& intervals) {
        int n = intervals.size();
        vector<int> res;
        vector<pair<Interval, int>> s_i;
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            s_i.push_back(make_pair(intervals[i], i));
        }
        sort(s_i.begin(), s_i.end(), [](const pair<Interval, int>& a, const pair<Interval, int> &b) -> bool {
            return a.first.start < b.first.start;
        });

        for(auto x : s_i) {
            cout<<"["<<x.first.start<<","<<x.first.end<<"],"<<x.second<<endl;
        }


        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            int val = intervals[i].end;
            cout<<val<<endl;
            //pair<Interval, int> temp = make_pair(Interval(val, val), 0);

            auto it = lower_bound(s_i.begin(), s_i.end(), val,
                                  [](const pair<Interval, int> &a, int val) -> bool {
                                      return a.first.start < val;
                                  });
            if (it != s_i.end()) {
                res[i] = it->second;
            } else {
                res[i] = -1;
            }

        }

        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: `res[i]` -- Are you going out-of-bounds here?  I don't see where `res` is sized appropriately with the requisite entries.  Try `res.at(i) = it->second;` and `res.at(i) = -1;` and see if a `std::out_of_range` exception is thrown.

Comment: Out-of-bounds and maybe your sorting is not what `std::lower_bound` expects. You sort the intervals by their start positions, but compare it to an end position afterwards. Can it happen, that after your sorting there is a start position after your wanted end position?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Correct. My bad, I got confused by the error, thought the issue was in my lower_bound. Thanks.

Comment: Problem got fixed after changing ```vector<int> res;``` to ```vector<int> res(n, -1);```.